# Xtext and Xtend - Add annotations before parameters in a method

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

I am trying to generate a Java code like the following.

```
public void create(@RequestBody final Resource resource) {
    return;
}
```

The Inferrer code snippet which I added for providing the @RequestBody is given below.

```
members += event.toMethod(event.action.name, typeRef(void)) [
    var dataType = map.get(method.action.name)
    parameters += event.toParameter(method.type.parameter.name, dataType.javaType)
    annotations += annotationRef("org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody");
    body = '''
        return;
    '''
```

The resulting generated code is like following.

```
@RequestBody
public void create(final Resource resource) {
    return;
}
```

What changes should I make in the xtend code in order to get the annotation before the parameter of method? Like `@RequestBody final Resource resource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add the Annotation to the Parameter itself. use a variable or the with clause

```
members += entity.toMethod("dummy", Void.TYPE.typeRef) [
parameters +=  entity.toParameter("someParam", String.typeRef) => [
    annotations += annotationRef("java.lang.Deprecated");
]
body = ''''''
]
```